# Getting ssh-keygen in Alpine docker

Tags: dockerfile, node-red, alpine-linux

for node-red new functionality Projects - where one can sync with a git repo, I need `ssh-keygen` in my Alpine docker Image. According to [Alpine Linux packages for v3.6](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=ssh-keygen&path=&name=&branch=v3.6&repo=main&arch=x86_64), it is in the `openssh-keygen` package.
Thus, I added the RUN commands as follows in the Dockerfile, with no luck.

```
......
RUN   apk update && \
      apk add --no-cache \
      openssh-keygen
......
```

I then test to see if it gets into the Image, by creating a container from the Image, doing a `docker exec -it containername sh` and then typing `ssh-keygen` - but do not find it.
Also not working if I replace `openssh-keygen` with `openssh` under the RUN command in the Dockerfile.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: The package name `openssh-keygen` is right. What does `which ssh-keygen` say inside the container? For me, it says `/usr/bin/ssh-keygen`.

Comment: Nothing return.... Do you bring the package in similar way? Let me then check my setup again...

Comment: Look at this pastebin - https://pastebin.com/ascreDGA

Comment: Hi @prasadk, if you do have time, could you look into my Dockerfile? [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/FvD1H3jg)

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with you Dockerfile. I built a docker image using the relevant parts of your Dockerfile and was able to get ssh-keygen installed inside the image.

Comment: Thank you! Dis you also 1st create a container from it, then logged into container to see if ssh-keygen is their?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to @PrasadK - which nudged me along, the answer to Node-
Red new Projects feature since version 0.18.3 - in order to have a remote repo - using this function in Node-Red Projects, the underlying docker image requires ssh-keygen. Do this in the Dockerfile with:

```
......
RUN   apk update && \
      apk add --no-cache \
      openssh-keygen
......
```

Comment: RUN apk add --no-cache --update openssh-keygen # in short